# have a button in a tableview cell print something

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, func, nstableviewcell

In my swift code below it features a button in a tableview cell. The problem is when i click on the button nothining is being printed. I dont know what to do next the button is connected and should work. My code does not use storyboard its all code. So there is not a storyboard connection issue

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let names = ["Katy Perry", "Jessica Biel", "Taylor Swift"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row // Set tag to identify which button is tapped
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let index = sender.tag
        let selectedName = names[index]
        print("Button tapped in cell for \(selectedName)")
    }
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        button.setTitle("Tap", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction() {
        print("Button in cell tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: Never add views directly to a table view cell. Add views to the cell's `contentView`. Update the constraints as well.

Comment: @HangarRash can you show me that in code.

Comment: Change `addSubview(button)` to `contentView.addSubview(button)`.

Answer (score -1):

Set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the cell's `contentView`, either in the cell's `init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` or in the table view's `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        ...
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ...
    }
}
```

Output:

> Button in cell tapped
> Button tapped in cell for Katy Perry

Answer (score -1):

This is the good way:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        ...
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeremyCaney Keep in mind that this person simply copied half of the other answer 10 minutes after that answer was posted.

Comment: @HangarRash: Thanks for highlighting that. I’ve removed my comment—and flagged this answer.